# How to curl convert to php? curl works but browers not work

Tags: php, image, curl, post

curl command is work

```
curl -X POST http://example.com/exmaple/example -T test.JPG
```

but, converted to php and not working in browers

```
$header = array(
    "Content-type: multipart/form-data"
);

$imageInfo = getimagesize("test.JPG");
$image = new CURLFile("test.JPG", $imageInfo['mime'], "image");

$data = array("name" => "test", "image" => $image);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/exmaple/example");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);

$raw = curl_exec($ch);

$curlError   = curl_error($ch);
$curlErrno   = curl_errno($ch);
$curlGetinfo = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

echo $raw;

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo "<br>Error: ".curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

result in brower

```
{ "code": 503, "type": "InternalServerException", "message": "Prediction failed" }
```

is Wrong convert?

Need to convert the image additionally in php code?

Comment: Your bash command is different from your PHP call: in bash you are not passing data. Check your PHP app server logs for that error and see if the data is not the root cause.